# Can't resolve conflicts in Git

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I want to resolve conflicts in Git in SourceTree but all the options appear as disabled

[image]

doing a Git status everything seems to be OK

```
On branch feature/Guerrilla_BG
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature/Guerrilla_BG'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

but going to bitbucket pull request I see this message:

```
Conflict: Modified on Source, Modified on Target

This file is in a conflicted state. You will need to resolve the conflict manually before you can merge this pull request.
```

Comment: Can you add 'git status' output to the question? Not sure how to do it with sourcetree.

Comment: It seems the PR can't be merged to the target branch because they have conflicts. Your local working tree is the newest state of the PR, which does not know about the state of the target branch yet. In other words, the conflicts are not local. Suppose the PR's target branch is `foo`. You could update your local `foo` or `origin/foo`. and then try to rebase PR onto the updated local foo or origin/foo, so that the conflicts will occur locally. Fix them and push and update the PR.